# R: Validate Data for Numeric and Non-Numeric Variables

Tags: r, validation, logical-operators, isnullorempty

I got problem with R that I cant figure it out.

Here's my dataframe "test1"
[dataframe1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4gy6.jpg)

I would like to validate if the data follows the rules 
(Rule1: if Q1=1, Q2=Blank
 Rule2: if Q1!=1, Q2!=Blank)
so that I can have the results as below
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSbBU.jpg)

However, I got the warning error "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used".

Can anyone helps me with this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Based on your rules, the 7th row, should be FALSE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the rules

```
df1$Result <- with(df1, (Q1==1 & Q2 == "")|(Q1 !=1 & Q2 !=""))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(i..key = 1:9, Q1 = c(1:3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3), 
  Q2 = c("", "abc", "fgdgg", "", "fdg", "", "dsfdsfds", "dfds", ""), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```